# Save WooCommerce product data to database based on other inputs calculation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

I am looking for a way to save data to a database base on other inputs, I have a `woocommerce_wp_text_input` and I use it to calculate the price per unit:

I use `woocommerce_wp_text_input( $ppuvnumber );` for getting the net weight (without packaging) and I use     `get_price();` for price. Then I use this formula to calculate the price per unit:

```
$product_att = wc_get_product ( $post->ID );    
$price_to_use = $product_att->get_price();
$amount_to_use = $product_att->get_meta( 'rasa_store_product_ppu_number' );
$calculation = round( $price_to_use/$amount_to_use, 2) ;
```

**I want to save the amount of `$calculation`  to database as `meta_key` .** Now I am a little bit confuse and have two questions:

1. Should I create a new `woocommerce_wp_text_input` and hide it?
2. Is it possible to save the result of `$calculation` to database without creating `woocommerce_wp_text_input`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible: You can use the `WC_Data` methods `update_meta_data()` and `save()` on the `WC_Product` object to add a custom field.

You just need to define under what meta key for that custom field.

On the code below replace `some_meta_key` by the desired meta key:

```
$product     = wc_get_product( $post->ID ); // get the product Object
$price       = $product->get_price(); // The product price
$ppu_number  = $product->get_meta( 'rasa_store_product_ppu_number' ); // Get some custom meta data
$calculation = round( $price/$ppu_number, 2) ; // Make the calculation

$product->update_meta_data('some_meta_key', $calculation); // Set the calculation as a new custom meta data
$product->save(); // Save to database
```

It should work.

You can also use WordPress `update_post_meta()` as follows *(the old way)*:

```
$product     = wc_get_product( $post->ID ); // get the product Object
$price       = $product->get_price(); // The product price
$ppu_number  = $product->get_meta( 'rasa_store_product_ppu_number' ); // Get some custom meta data
$calculation = round( $price/$ppu_number, 2) ; // Make the calculation

update_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'some_meta_key', $calculation ); // Set and save the calculation as a new custom meta data
```

Comment: Thanks, I see this error `There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.`
 and in email I get it writes `Call to a member function update_meta_data() on null`

Comment: @M.SallarRabiei Its depends how and where you are using the code. I have tested both codes and they work… on emails, you need to get order items  first and in a foreach loop and then you need to get the product object… Then my code will work.

Comment: I put the codes in a function and than I use `add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'function_name');` , is it correct way to use the code?

Comment: I try use the code in different ways, but I face this error: `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_price() on boolean`

Comment: Ok, it solved, I use  `global $post;` and it works, thank @LoicTheAztec